# Rails: Should I throw an exception if an item cannot be saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I find myself in this situation very often. Sometimes I just take for granted that the record will be saved correctly if I'm in a rush, but I feel as that not being a good practice. I see sometimes placing the `if save` condition. The question arises here: *what are the situations where a record cannot be saved?*

Comment: If you want errors to be thrown you can use `save!` it throws if validations fail.

Comment: When it fails validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *what are the situations where a record cannot be saved?*

If any of your validations fail. (Or of course HW failure, database connection loss etc occurs).

> *Should I throw an exception if an item cannot be saved?*

If you want an invalid record to result in an exception being thrown, you don't need to do it yourself. Rails can already do it:

If you have a `User` model with a couple of validations (`email` and `name` must be present), you could:

```
user.save!
```

> With save! validations always run. If any of them fail ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid gets raised.

But you probably don't want an exception to be raised in such a case. Because it is rather "common" for a user to not enter a valid password, for example. But
you should handle errors and the way this is commonly done is:

```
if user.save
  #
else
  # handle error
end
```

> By default, save always run validations. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and save returns false.

As a general guideline for choosing between conditionals and exceptions I like [this statement from DHH](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7335211):

> Why would the delivery of the emails fail? Because your SMTP server is down? That's an exceptional state, handle it with exceptions -- not with conditions.